# The timeout time set by the wait_event_interruptible_timeout function deviates too much from the expected value?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I added the following callback function to a driver code in the kernel source code of Linux version 3.10. However, when I called the read function at the application layer, I found that the waiting time for `wait_event_interruptible_timeout(WaitQueue, IrqOccurred, msecs_to_jiffies(8));` was not enough. I expected it to be `8ms`, but according to the `dmesg` print, the result from `begin1` to `end1` was only `1ms`, which is also a huge difference. What is the problem?

.read:

```
static ssize_t spiio_drv_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
        int value = 0;
        char userValue = value ? 1:0;
        int ret = 0;
        printk("this is read. IrqOccurred = %d\n", IrqOccurred);
        ret = wait_event_interruptible_timeout(WaitQueue, IrqOccurred, msecs_to_jiffies(8));
        printk("wait end-timeout, ret = %d, IrqOccurred = %d\n", ret, IrqOccurred);
        mutex_lock(&RWLock);
        IrqOccurred = 0;  //need lock
        mutex_unlock(&RWLock);
        return 0;
}
```

a part of `dmesg`:

```
[ 2328.690083] wait end-timeout, ret = 0, IrqOccurred = 0
[ 2367.397528] this is open
[ 2367.407615] this is read. IrqOccurred = 0
[ 2367.410102] wait end-timeout, ret = 0, IrqOccurred = 0
[ 2720.973936] this is open
[ 2720.983939] this is read. IrqOccurred = 0
[ 2720.990113] wait end-timeout, ret = 0, IrqOccurred = 0
[ 2744.733346] this is open
[ 2744.743254] this is read. IrqOccurred = 0                      
[ 2744.750082] wait end-timeout, ret = 0, IrqOccurred = 0          
[ 2748.768938] this is open
[ 2748.779009] this is read. IrqOccurred = 0                       -----begin1
[ 2748.780087] wait end-timeout, ret = 0, IrqOccurred = 0          -----end1
[ 2751.712281] this is open
[ 2751.722623] this is read. IrqOccurred = 0                       -----begin2
[ 2751.730092] wait end-timeout, ret = 0, IrqOccurred = 0**        -----end2
```